# Fluid not baked from script but only from gui

Tags: scripting, fluid-simulation

While baking from GUI perfectly works, I have no animation if baked using the script below.

[image: pic]

What else could I try?

`sudo blender --background fluid.blend --python bake.py`

`cat bake.py`

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for object in scene.objects:
        for modifier in object.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'FLUID':
                if modifier.fluid_type == 'DOMAIN':
                    print("Baking fluid")
                    object.select_set(True)
                    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
                    bpy.ops.fluid.bake_data()
            elif modifier.type == 'CLOTH':
                print("Baking cloth")
                override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': object, 'point_cache': modifier.point_cache}
                bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(override)
                bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=True)
            elif modifier.type == 'PARTICLE_SYSTEM':
                print("Baking particles")
                override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': object, 'point_cache': modifier.particle_system.point_cache}
                bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(override)
                bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=True)
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

Log:

```
Blender 2.92.0 (hash 02948a2cab44 built 2021-04-25 11:39:34)
Read prefs: /root/.config/blender/2.92/config/userpref.blend
Read blend: /home/user/tmp/fluid.blend
Baking fluid
Info: Fluid: Bake Data complete! (0.32)
Baking particles
Info: Saved "fluid.blend"
Info: Saved "fluid.blend"
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
if modifier.type == 'FLUID':
    if modifier.fluid_type == 'DOMAIN':
                    print("baking fluid %s %s"%(modifier.type, object.name))
                    override = {'scene': scene, 'active_object': object, 'point_cache': modifier.domain_settings.point_cache}
                    bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake_all()
                    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)
```